# How to resolve an object in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, orchardcms

I have a service class in a module in Orchard CMS that it is dependent on some dependency such as `IContentManager` and it implemented `IDependency` interface.
in my controllers i used it by injecting and it works pretty good.

my service:

```
public class AddressService : IAddressService
{
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    private readonly IOrchardServices _orchardService;
    private readonly IRepository<StatePartRecord> _stateRepository;
    private readonly IContentDefinitionManager _contentDefinitionManager;
    public AddressService(IContentManager contentManager, IOrchardServices orchardService, IRepository<StatePartRecord> stateRepository, IContentDefinitionManager contentDefinitionManager)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _orchardService = orchardService;
        _stateRepository = stateRepository;
        _contentDefinitionManager = contentDefinitionManager;
    }
...
}

public interface IAddressService : IDependency    { ... }
```

my question is that, in my custom class that is just a simple class how do i resolve and create an object instance of my service class in it?

my simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{

   public SomeMethod() 
   {
      var addressService = // a method to resolve 'AddressService' class from IOC container

      // Do somthing with 'addressService' ...
   }
}
```

**Edit** I already knew that we can use `AddressService` by injecting way, but i can't use injection in some cases such as `static classes` or `extension method`... ,Because of that i need to resolve dynamically `AddressService` and create instance by some method (that i guess it would be found in Orchard Framework) where i had to use it.

**In fact I need a method that takes a Type as argument and create instance of the passed Type and return the created object.**

Comment: Would it be suitable for you to create the static method so that it would take the result of service as parameter and return whatever object you need? Then you could call service in controllers return your object, pass it to your static extension and vuala... What kind of extension are you creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an argument (the service) into the constructor which implements the interface. Then you should be able to access the service (IOC Sorts out instantiation etc):

```
public class MyClass
{
   private IAddressService addressService;
   public MyClass(IAddressService service) 
   {
      addressService = service;    
   }

   public SomeMethod() 
   {
      // Do something with 'addressService' ...
   }
}
```

Or is your question not as obvious as what I have understood it to be??

On fifth reading of your question, I think you may be asking how to register your interface so that it uses your implementation?

Not sure how Ioc is done in Orchard but in Windsor (which I use at work) we register dependencies similar to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public SomeMethod(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
     container.Register( Component.For<IAddressService>().ImplementedBy<AddressService>());
  }
}
```

EDIT: Made mistake in code so added constructor, instead of passing the value to the method.

Comment: Thanks man.I've edited my question and i added some more detail of issue.

Comment: This is not correct Orchard doesn't use Castle for IOC it uses Autofac. Also you didn't provide a way how to acces the IOC container in Orchard.

Comment: Just found this which may not give you the answer but may help your investigations: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works#DependencyInjection

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Your class itself will have to be instantiated by something. It should be instantiated when injected into something else. This question should be modified to present a real example rather than a "hello world what if" scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Why not register your other class into the Autofac container also? Then you could let your container take care of wiring up your class. Its not good idea to have reference to service which is managed by Autofac injected into class that is not. Services should be injected into controllers that are managed. If you need to combine service functionality just make another service where you can do that....

Otherwise, you need a reference to Autofac `Container` and then call the `Resolve` method. So, how you get that? You can look at how that is done in `DefaultContentManager` where componets are resolvet through `IComponentContext`, but of course `DefaultContentManager` is managed by Autofac and there is no static method that I could find in Orchard that will let you get the reference to the Autofac container (if there were it would be a static getter in `OrchardStarter`).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using IWorkContexAccessor. 
[You can see code here.](https://gist.github.com/denza/9954239)